# Creating jquery object array and posting its values on form submit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have dynamicly added html elements(selectlists) in a form :

```
//Dynamicly adding selectlist elements
function newshit() {
    i = i + 1
    $("#mytable").append("<tr><td><div id='div" + i + "'><select id='elem" + i + "' name='elem" + i + "' class='ted'></select><input type='button' value='-' id='buttonminus" + i + "' style='width:5%;' onclick='removeelem(elem" + i + ",buttonminus" + i + "," + i + ")'/></div></td></tr>")
    getitems("elem" + i)
}

//filling lists
function getitems(item) {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Content("~/Stok/Items/")', {}, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, c) {
            $("#" + item).append("<option value='" + c.Value + "' title='" + c.Text + "' label='" + c.Text + "'>" + c.Text + "</option>")
        })
    })
}

//removing element, when button next to it used
function removeelem(elem,buttonminus,i) {
    if ($("select").length > 1) {
        $("#div" + i).closest('tr').empty().remove()
    } else if ($("select").length <= 1) {
        alert("At least 1 of items must be chosen to create a group!")
    }
}

//checking elements and values existence
function check() {
    var slcts = $("select").serialize();
    alert(slcts)
}
```

im trying to get the value of each selectlist's selected option value and put them into an array than send them to my controller on form submit.

How can i achive this?

Comment: Why do this client side, why not just deal with it on the server side - these values will all be posted.

Comment: show me an example about it then :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to check this, but I think that the following should work:

1. Change your code so that the format of your ids is something like:

   id="elem[0]"

Then if your controller has a signature something like this:

```
public ActionResult Something(IEnumerable<string> elem)
{

}
```

Then his should "just work".

Comment: what should i do to create element with id="elem[0]" this way?
by string works or creating an objectArray?.

Comment: Exactly the same way that you are currently doing it, just need to change your string slightly.

Comment: are u sure that is working? cause i ve some trouble with it. can u show a sample of both view and controller parts.

Comment: No, don't have a easy way to check to hand.  If you look in the posted formcollection, what do you have?

Comment: i made it at last yep ur code works just need to use a model between and `<select name="elem[' + i + ']"></select>` should start with `i = 0;` cause `IEnumerable` starts with `0` so its solved! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like -

```
var selectdata = $("select").serialize()
```

This will return a string in the form `<select name attribute1>=<chosen value1>&<select name attribute2>=<chosen value2>` etc. You'd need to add a 'name' attribute to your select HTML when you create it for this to work.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/fZXha/

You could then put the `selectdata` variable in a hidden field before the form was posted or send it via AJAX using the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) methods.

Comment: Why do you want to send an array? Do you want to access an array in your controller?

Comment: reason that i wanna send it as array to know how many items dynamicly created

Comment: It is surely relatively trivial to split this string on '&' to get an array of name/values.